# The value of the local variable category is not used

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
    String category[] = request.getParameterValues("category");
}
```

`String Category[]` line displays:

> "The value of the local variable category is not used"

Secondly, I want to pass this array to my controller class to set as its getters/setter:

```java
    public class Controller {
        private String[] category;
    
        public Controller(String[] category) {
            super();
            this.category[] = category;
        }
    }
```

This throws error:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String"

I am beginner. Please advise how can I fix these two errors/warnings

Best regards

Comment: "*The value of the local variable category is not used*" is a warning, IDE just warns you, that you have a variable which you're not using. Generally speaking, `Type[]` and `Type` are two completely different types; one is an `array of Type` whilst another is a `Type`. You're having `category` and not `category[]`, as your field identifier, so try `this.category = category;` instead.

Comment: when I use `this.category = category;` its warn that The value of the field Controller.category is not used. `private String[] category;' is array and also constructor passing array like this `public Controller(String[] category) {` then where I am using String instead of String[]?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to say. **Warning** is a warning, which doesn't say your code is illegal; however, IDE has some code inspection mechanism behind the scenes, and it *knows* and *sees* that you're having a variable, which you never use - why to have that variable then? what's the purpose of having `x` if you're never using, in anything, that `x`? this is what IDE tells you, nothing more, nothing less. Regarding second point: `String[]` is a type called *Array of Strings*, and `String` is just a reference type, which defines string objects (character arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are trying to set an array, which is technically a reference object, to another array(another reference object). When you are defining your arrays you will need to have the square brackets but when trying to call on the variable you won't always need it.

```
this.category[] = category;
```

needs to become

```
this.category = category;
```

This line will give you what you want and define category. I know you said you were a beginner but I'd try looking into ArrayLists because they will make your life a lot easier in things like this.